# How to use both software serial and hardware serial on Ardruino Micro

Tags: gps, arduino

I am trying to read data from two GPS modules. One is connected Software Serial, and one is connected to Hardware Serial. I only get data from Hardware Serial.

See code:
https://github.com/kaiaw/1510-arduino/blob/master/parsingGPS/parsingGPS.ino

We are using the leo_parsing example from the Adafruit GPS Library
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GPS-Library/blob/master/examples/leo_parsing/leo_parsing.ino

Do any of you have any experience with this?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Would you mind posting some code as to what you've tried? Presumably what you are wanting to know is why you are not getting data from the Software Serial?

Comment: Yes, thats what i want to know, you can finde the code here https://github.com/kaiaw/1510-arduino/blob/master/parsingGPS/parsingGPS.ino

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use software serial, you need to comment out the hardware serial code:

```
// If using software serial, keep these lines enabled
// (you can change the pin numbers to match your wiring):
SoftwareSerial camSerial(8, 7);
Adafruit_GPS GPS_CAM(&camSerial);

// If using hardware serial, comment
// out the above two lines and enable these two lines instead:
// **if using software serial, comment out these next two lines**
//Adafruit_GPS GPS_PERSON(&Serial1);
//HardwareSerial personSerial = Serial1;
```